# To minimize surface area of integer cuboid of ​the known volume

Tags: optimization, algorithms, 3d, volume, minimal-surfaces

There is a [cuboid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboid) (a * b * c), (a, b, c ∈ N), whose side lengths are all integers.

**S** (Surface area of a cuboid) = 2 * (ab + bc + ca).

**V** (Volume of a cuboid) = a * b * c = n.

I need to minimize **S**, provided that I specified the volume (**V**).

Is there some algorithm or way to get **a, b, c**, excepted a brute force?

Answer (score 0):

It is optimized version of naive algorithm (I hope that it will help). Unfortunately I don't know fastest algorithm:

https://github.com/LmTinyToon/Puzzles/blob/master/CodingGame/Community/the-max-surface-box.cpp